# PopupControlExtender in ajaxToolkit is not working with tinymce enabled textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tinymce-4

I have a website that developed by using ASP.NET.
In there when user focus on a text box small tool tip appear on the right side of the text box. I am using ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender  to achieve it.
This is my code.,

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" AutoComplete="off" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="6000" class="tinymce"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTest" PopupControlID="tipCity" Position="Right"></ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender>
```

This is working fine. But problem is I am using  text editor called tinymce for this textbox. So after applying it This PopupControlExtender is not displaying the message.

I am using below code to include tinymce.

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            resize: true,
            mode: "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector: "tinymce",
            encoding: "xml",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
             "advlist lists link preview",
             "searchreplace",
             "directionality"
            ],
            toolbar1: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | preview",
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: true,


            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('SaveContent', function (ed) {
                    ed.content = ed.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
                });
            }
        });
```

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'text_control_id');
}

prm.add_pageLoaded(function (sender, e) {
    LoadTinyMCE();
});
```